# how enable jquery autocompletecombobox with data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I disable and enable jQuery [autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) using the following:

```
$("#classno").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input")
            .autocomplete("option", "disabled", true).prop("disabled",true); 

$("#classno").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input")
             .autocomplete("option", "disabled", true).prop("disabled",false);
```

It works fine, but when I enable it I can't see the values which were added previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
$("#classno").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input").autocomplete( "disable" );

$("#classno").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input").autocomplete( "enable" );
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-disable

Comment: i need to clear the input field write after i inset a value.how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

seems you are not enabling autocomplete in your second call and only enabling `input`. So instead of:

```
$("#classno").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input")
         .autocomplete("option", "disabled", true).prop("disabled",false);
```

you should try:

```
$("#classno").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input")
         .autocomplete("option", "disabled", false).prop("disabled",false);
```

you can use `$("#classno").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input").val('')`

Comment: hello thnks it works.then i need to clear input field when i select a value how can i do it